# Spring Data Redis using '+inf' to specify unlimited bounds of ZSetOperations.rangeByScore

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Using the Redis CLI you can [query a sorted set by range](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) with an unlimited upper bound:

```
zrangebyscore my_key 0 +inf
```

Represented by the `+inf` as well as an unlimited lower bound: `-inf`. This retrieves the range from 0 to the last member.

Spring Data Redis provides an interface to this Redis command through [this method signature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ZSetOperations.html#rangeByScore-K-double-double-):

```
Set<V> rangeByScore(K key, double min, double max, long offset, long count);
```

and

```
Set<V> rangeByScore(K key, double min, double max);
```

These only allow you to supply a double as the bounds.

**How do you specify `+inf` or `-inf` to the bounds of ZRANGEBYSCORE using Spring Data Redis ?**

The only mention of it is in the [changelog](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#new-in-1-6-0) so it's supported in some way but I can't find any mention of it elsewhere.

Comment: Spring Data Redis 1.6 introduced `RedisZSetCommands.zRangeByScoreWithScores(byte[], Range, Limit)` on connection level but not on operations level (Template API). There are two open tickets ([DATAREDIS-236](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-236), [DATAREDIS-362](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-362)) heading in that direction.

Comment: @mp911de thanks, I saw a byte array representation of `+inf` in the Spring data code but couldn't see where it was being used. I think I'll wait until those fixes are in before using it then.

Comment: Feel free to submit a pull request to speed up availability.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` to represent -inf and +inf, I've tested on my machine, which works well(with spring-boot-starter-data-redis version=2.2.4.RELEASE)
(They are both double values)

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions you can specify the range with `Bound.unbounded()`.

```
Flux<V> rangeByScore(K key, Range<Double> range, Limit limit)
```

For example:

```
Range.of(Bound.inclusive(start), Bound.unbounded())
```

See `Range` class for other factory methods like `leftUnbounded` / `rightUnbounded`.

I used this with a redis version below 6.2. With 6.2+ the zrange semantics changed.